# What is the alternative of "window.autoRefresh" for safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, settimeout, page-refresh

In safari `window.autoRefresh` doesn't get triggered. How to make this to work? And I dint get any examples of `window.autoRefresh` and documentation of the same.

This code autofreshes a div not page

```
if(window.autoRefresh==true)//without this condition, refresh works fine.
        {
            if (typeof autoRefreshTimeout == 'undefined'){
            autoRefreshTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    clearTimeout(autoRefreshTimeout);
                    autoRefreshTimeout = undefined;
                    dosomething();
                    }

                }, 30000);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `window.autoRefresh`. You can set it as custom property if you want. Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, if you want to refresh multiple times after several milliseconds.

```js
var autoRefreshTimeout;
var count = 0;
    
// function that change div content
function dosomething() {
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
  count++;
}

// start timeout/interval
function startRefresh() {
  // check if already refreshing
  if(!window.autoRefresh) {
    // set custom property
    window.autoRefresh = true;

    // autoRefreshTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    autoRefreshTimeout = setInterval(function() {
      console.log('refresh');
      dosomething();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

// stop timeout/interval
function stopRefresh() {
  if (window.autoRefresh) {
    // set custom property
    window.autoRefresh = false;

    // clearTimeout(autoRefreshTimeout);
    clearInterval(autoRefreshTimeout);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='startRefresh()'>start</button>
<button onclick='stopRefresh()'>stop</button>
<div id="counter"></div>
```